# Can I write the solution of the ODE in the following way?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $A:\mathbb {R} \to M_n (\mathbb{R}) $ and $h: \mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {R}^n$ be smooth bounded  functions. Consider $\Phi : \mathbb {R} \to M _n (\mathbb {R})$ as a fundamental matrix of the ODE
$$\dot {y} = A (t) y. $$

Suppose that we know that $\varphi: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ solve the following ODE

$$\dot{y} = A(t)y + h(t), $$

and $\varphi(t) \to 0,$ when $t \rightarrow -\infty $.

Note that using the constants variantion formula

$\varphi (t) = \Phi (t)\left [\Phi^{-1}(t_0) \varphi (t_0) +\int_{t_0}^{t} \Phi^{-1} (s) h (s)  ds\right],$
forall $t_0$ $\in $ $\mathbb {R} $.

I would like to know if under these assumptions

$$\varphi (t) = \Phi (t)\int_{-\infty}^{t} \Phi^{-1} (s) h (s)  ds ?$$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: How could it be in general? Take a one dimensional system with $A=1$ and $h=0$. Then $\phi(t) = y_0 e^t$ which cannot be expressed as in the last equation above. In general, it is a good idea to examine a simple case that satisfies the assumptions first.

Comment: Thx for the answer :), you are right!!!